# tns stopped recognizing my device. Cannot find connected devices

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing an app using 
nativescript 5.4.0,
tns-core-modules 5.4.2,
tns-android 5.4.0

In the past days I started receiving an error saying Cannot find connected devices.

Before everything was working fine. I was able to deploy my app on my RedMi 3 device and debug it from the console using tns run android.

I tried a lot of stuff. Reinstalling nativescript and android, reconfiguration of the device (usb debugging is active)...

adb is able to recognize the device, but tns is not. Additionally I am able to build a debug version as well.

I installed and tried on a new machine and continued to having this problem. I even tried with a different device.

```
Error: Trying to handle SIGINT event. CLI overrides this behavior and does not allow handling SIGINT as this causes issues with Ctrl + C in terminal
    at process.on (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\nativescript-cli.js:22:22)
    at C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:122:15
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at load (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:120:21)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\signal-exit\index.js:35:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\proper-lockfile\lib\lockfile.js:296:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
Looking for project in 'C:\app\challenger'
Project directory is 'C:\app\challenger'.
Loading extensions.
Asserting extension nativescript-cloud is installed.
Extension nativescript-cloud is installed.
Asserting extension nativescript-starter-kits is installed.
Extension nativescript-starter-kits is installed.
System information:
{ platform: 'win32',
  shell: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
  os: 'Windows 10 Pro 6.3.17134',
  procArch: 'x64',
  nodeVer: '8.11.3',
  npmVer: '5.6.0',
  nodeGypVer: null,
  nativeScriptCliVersion: '5.4.0',
  gitVer: '2.18.0.windows.1',
  dotNetVer: '4.7.03056',
  javacVersion: '1.8.0_211',
  javaVersion: '1.8.0_211',
  adbVer: '1.0.41',
  androidInstalled: true,
  monoVer: null,
  gradleVer: null,
  isAndroidSdkConfiguredCorrectly: true,
  xcodeVer: undefined,
  xcodeprojLocation: null,
  itunesInstalled: false,
  cocoaPodsVer: undefined,
  isCocoaPodsWorkingCorrectly: false,
  isCocoaPodsUpdateRequired: false,
  pythonInfo: null }
Starting watch on killswitch C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Temp\stefa\KillSwitches\cli
Initializing analytics statuses.
spawn: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\detached-processes\cleanup-process.js" "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\bootstrap.js"
Analytics statuses:  { TrackFeatureUsage: 'enabled', TrackExceptions: 'enabled' }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Check Local Build Setup',
  label: 'Starting',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'CLI' },
  value: undefined }
spawn: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\analytics\analytics-broker-process.js" "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\bootstrap.js"
Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
The Android SDK is installed.
A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
Javac is installed and is configured properly.
The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Check Local Build Setup',
  label: 'Finished: Is setup correct: true',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'CLI' },
  value: undefined }
Installed Android Targets are:  [ 'android-28' ]
Directories found in C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools are 28.0.3
Versions found in C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools are 28.0.3
Selected version is:  28.0.3
Selected targetSdk is: 28
Validate options for platform: Android
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'pageview',
  path: 'run android',
  title: 'run android',
  customDimensions: { cd5: 'CLI', cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false' } }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Options',
  label: '{"hmr":true,"log":"trace","$0":"_localpath","bundle":"webpack","profileDir":"private"}',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'CLI' },
  value: undefined }
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: { type: 'PreviewAppData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Preview App Data',
  platform: 'Android',
  label: 'Android',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'CLI' } }
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
startLookingForDevices; platform is Android
Options for ios-device-discovery { platform: 'Android',
  shouldReturnImmediateResult: false,
  emulator: false }
spawn: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "start-server"
Result when throw error is false:
{ stdout: '', stderr: '', exitCode: 0 }
  exitCode: 3221226356 }
{ characteristics: 'nosdcard nosdcard',
  date: 'Thu Nov 22 02:07:05 CST 2018',
  'date.utc': '1542823625',
  description: 'kenzo-user 6.0.1 MMB29M 8.11.22 release-keys',
  'device.ninur': '64687',
  'display.hardware': '',
  'display.id': 'MMB29M',
  fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/kenzo/kenzo:6.0.1/MMB29M/8.11.22:user/release-keys',
  flavor: 'kenzo-user',
  'hardware.version': 'D2-2',
  host: 'c3-miui-ota-bd74.bj',
  id: 'MMB29M',
  'network.type': '',
  product: 'kenzo',
  project: '',
  'software.version': 'Android6.0.1_10',
  tags: 'release-keys',
  type: 'user',
  user: 'builder',
  all_codenames: 'REL',
  base_os: '',
  bsp: '0.8.1_170609',
  codename: 'REL',
  external: '',
  incremental: '8.11.22',
  internal: '',
  preview_sdk: '0',
  release: '6.0.1',
  sdk: '23',
  security_patch: '2018-07-01',
  versiontype: '',
  board: 'msm8952',
  brand: 'Xiaomi',
  'cpu.abi': 'arm64-v8a',
  'cpu.abilist': 'arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi',
  'cpu.abilist32': 'armeabi-v7a,armeabi',
  'cpu.abilist64': 'arm64-v8a',
  cuptsm: 'XIAOMI|ESE|02|01',
  device: 'kenzo',
  first_api_level: '22',
  locale: 'en-GB',
  'locale.language': 'en',
  'locale.region': 'US',
  manufacturer: 'Xiaomi',
  mod_device: 'kenzo_global',
  model: 'Redmi Note 3',
  name: 'kenzo' }
{ characteristics: 'nosdcard nosdcard',
  date: 'Thu Nov 22 02:07:05 CST 2018',
  'date.utc': '1542823625',
  description: 'kenzo-user 6.0.1 MMB29M 8.11.22 release-keys',
  'device.ninur': '64687',
  'display.hardware': '',
  'display.id': 'MMB29M',
  fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/kenzo/kenzo:6.0.1/MMB29M/8.11.22:user/release-keys',
  flavor: 'kenzo-user',
  'hardware.version': 'D2-2',
  host: 'c3-miui-ota-bd74.bj',
  id: 'MMB29M',
  'network.type': '',
  product: 'kenzo',
  project: '',
  'software.version': 'Android6.0.1_10',
  tags: 'release-keys',
  type: 'user',
  user: 'builder',
  all_codenames: 'REL',
  base_os: '',
  bsp: '0.8.1_170609',
  codename: 'REL',
  external: '',
  incremental: '8.11.22',
  internal: '',
  preview_sdk: '0',
  release: '6.0.1',
  sdk: '23',
  security_patch: '2018-07-01',
  versiontype: '',
  board: 'msm8952',
  brand: 'Xiaomi',
  'cpu.abi': 'arm64-v8a',
  'cpu.abilist': 'arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi',
  'cpu.abilist32': 'armeabi-v7a,armeabi',
  'cpu.abilist64': 'arm64-v8a',
  cuptsm: 'XIAOMI|ESE|02|01',
  device: 'kenzo',
  first_api_level: '22',
  locale: 'en-GB',
  'locale.language': 'en',
  'locale.region': 'US',
  manufacturer: 'Xiaomi',
  mod_device: 'kenzo_global',
  model: 'Redmi Note 3',
  name: 'kenzo' }
spawn: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "devices"
execFile: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "-s" "6301b4cf" "shell" "getprop" "ro.product.manufacturer"
Error while checking for devices. { Error: Command failed: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 6301b4cf shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 3221226356,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb -s 6301b4cf shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer' }
spawn: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "devices"
spawn: C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager.bat "list" "avds"
Error while trying to get InstallDir property for \Software\Oracle\VirtualBox. More info: Error: QUERY command exited with code 1:

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value..
spawn: player 0
Configuration error for Genymotion { stdout: '', stderr: 'spawn player ENOENT', exitCode: 'ENOENT' }
execFile: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "-s" "6301b4cf" "shell" "getprop" "ro.product.manufacturer"
Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Command failed: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 6301b4cf shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer

To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.
Error while initializing devicesService: Exception: Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Command failed: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 6301b4cf shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer

To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.
Error: Cannot find connected devices.
Emulator start failed with: Command failed: C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 6301b4cf shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer

To list currently connected devices and verify that the specified identifier exists, run 'tns device'.
To list available emulator images, run 'tns device <Platform> --available-devices'.
    at Errors.fail (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:126:28)
    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:136:21)
    at DevicesService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\mobile\mobile-core\devices-service.js:444:34)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\mobile\mobile-core\devices-service.js:11:65)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Actually it's not tns command whose job is to identify your devices connected. It's called ADB, a tool from Android SDK which is responsible for identifying your device / emulator, install / debug APK on your device / emulator. Try running `adb devices` (assuming your path variable is updated to point adb tool from Android SDK), it should list your device. If it doesn't try restarting it `adb kill-server` / `adb start-server`. Once you see your device here, tns commands will be able to use it.

Comment: Hey @Manoj tnx for the quick respond. As I mentioned adb is able to recognize the device. When I run  adb devices. I am able to see my device. I also did try with adb kill-server / adb start-server.  At the end I reinstalled Android SDK Build-Tools. This seemed to help. Now it is working. Could be that I have updated Android sdk and something was misplaced or some other issue. Nevertheless thank you for your help.